# How to start playing video by clicking on it without controls using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-video

I use standart video html5 player in my react app:

```
const Video = ({ url, contentType }) => (
  <video poster={url}>
    <source src={`${url}#t=0.01`} type={contentType} className="video" />
  </video>
)
```

and i would like to hide controls and play/pause video by clicking on it, i found how to do it by using `javascript`:

```
var overlay = document.getElementById('video-overlay');
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var videoPlaying = false;
overlay.onclick = function() {
    if (videoPlaying) {
        video.pause();
        videoPlaying = false;
    }
    else {
        video.play();
        videoPlaying = true;
    }
}
```

but i don't know how to replace it with react, i tried to add `onClick{e => e.play}` but it didn't work, also i checked what `e` contains, it doesn't contain any `isPlaying` flags or `play/pause` possibililties, please tell me how can i to it properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reasons that wouldn't work:

1. You didn't **call** `play`, you just referred to it. To call it, you'd need `()`.
2. The argument passed to an event handler isn't the element the event occurred on, it's an Event object (in React's case, a synthetic one). You can access the element you hooked the event on via the event's `currentTarget` property:

   ```
    <video poster={url} onClick={e => e.currentTarget.play()}>
   ```

   or with destructuring

   ```
    <video poster={url} onClick={({currentTarget}) => currentTarget.play()}>
   ```